# Web Service calls no longer work in background when background audio mode is enabled on iOS10

Tags: ios, audio, nsurlsession, ios10

I have a music player here which fires a delegate method when a track is finished playing and calls a web service in the background to get the next track.

Everything functions correctly up to the web service call (Delegate method fires, next track method is called). The network call, which uses NSURLSession, fails to get to the completion block and upon resume of the app (i.e the app re-entering the foreground state) enters the failed completion block and throws a socket error as follows:

```
nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 12, 1024 bytes): [57] Socket is not connected
```

This is new behaviour as of iOS10 and worked perfectly from iOS7-9. Can someone please advise as to whats changed and a potential solution?

Comment: Hey @patrickjquinn, I got similar problem with background networking when iPhone is on lock screen. Any luck investigating it?

Comment: Sadly no, the exact same thing happens when you switch the networking over to the background thread in the app delegate, they've changed memory management in iOS10 seemingly and apps get totally de-alloced much more quickly. Just wish someone here would share some insight.

Comment: So if you like me are having this issue in the context of a music player, having an AvAudioPlayer play an empty wav file on a loop in between making requests should fix it. iOS 10 seems to just shut the app down pretty much as soon the bg audio stops.

Comment: Isn't completition block not available when working on background?